# C libarchive erro: Unsupported ZIP compression

Tags: c++, arquivo-zip

Estou tentando ler um arquivo .zip usando libarchive mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro em **archive_read_data()**

> Unsupported ZIP compression method (deflation)

O mesmo erro ocorre com todos os outros formatos de compressão.

segue o código:

```
archive* a;
archive_entry* entry;

a = archive_read_new();
assert(a != NULL);

archive_read_support_filter_all(a);
archive_read_support_format_all(a);

int result = archive_read_open_filename(a, "Data.zip", 0);

if (result != ARCHIVE_OK) {
    std::cerr << archive_error_string(a) << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

while (archive_read_next_header(a, &entry) == ARCHIVE_OK) {
    auto file_size = archive_entry_size(entry);

    std::cout << archive_entry_pathname(entry) << ", size: " << file_size << std::endl;

    auto buffer = new char[file_size];

    auto read_result = archive_read_data(a, buffer, file_size);

    if (read_result <= 0) {
        std::cerr << archive_error_string(a) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } else if (read_result > 0) {
        std::ofstream file(archive_entry_pathname(entry), std::ios::binary);
        file.write(buffer, file_size);
        file.close();
    }

    delete[] buffer;    
}

archive_read_finish(a);
```

O que eu estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Você está lendo um arquivo de tamanho arbitrário para dentro de um **buffer**, isso faz com que a leitura dos dados fique limitada ao tamanho da memória disponível. Você precisa segmentar a leitura do arquivo em blocos menores. Veja [neste](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples#a-universal-decompressor) exemplo.